# Connect to remote machine using subprocess

Tags: python, ssh

I would like to connect to a remote machine and would also like to execute certain commands over there.

**Details:**

Remote Machine: It is a linux machine.

Local Machine: It is windows 7 machine.

My Python code is on windows machine.

```
import subprocess
import sys

HOST="eseki.rnd.sozi.se"
# Ports are handled in ~/.ssh/config since we use OpenSSH
COMMAND="uname -a"

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()

if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
    print result
```

However, when I execute this code, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ABC\workspace\HelloWorldPython\src\SSHTestModule.py", line 16, in <module>
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

What should I do to connect to a remote machine using Python?

Comment: do you have ssh installed on your win box? ssh isn't something microsoft provides out-of-the-box...

Comment: No, I haven't installed it

Comment: then how do you expect python to be able to execute a program which hasn't been installed?

Comment: My bad, I will install ssh and edit the question if I get stuck.

Comment: Definitely look into paramiko instead if you are having problems getting a reasonable SSH setup on windows (by reasonable, I mean without Cygwin)

Answer (score 0):

You either don't have an ssh client installed on your local machine, or it isn't in the PATH variable.

Either way, I recommend you look into a library specifically designed for ssh in lieu of using subprocess (e.g., http://www.paramiko.org/)